# Windows 10 (Pro) can't stop sign in screen for local admin account

Tags: windows, windows-10, login

I have a laptop which I put Windows 10 Pro on and I have a local (non MS) account which is an admin with no password. The problem I have is when I sleep the computer it shows me the "Sign In" screen, and while I do not need a password I still need to click the sign in button which in this scenario I cannot do (as it is woken from an external PC for streaming purposes).

Is there a way to remove this sign in step? Once I press sign in manually I am on the PC (As there is no password). I have no option for "require sign in after sleep" as there is no password set. I have also tried doing the regedit "NoScreenLock" key and restarted, which didn't do anything.

Is there a way to just remove the login screen when I sleep the computer?

Comment: I just dont want the "sign in" button to appear, as I am just sleeping the machine I am already logged in, I dont know why it shows me a "sign in" button as it knows who I am and I have no password. I can work around this issue by giving the account a password to show the "Require Sign In After Sleep" option, but it seems like I should be able to do this without a password.

Comment: Do you mean you want to disable login screen on windows after sleep?

Answer (score 0):

*Settings* → *Accounts* → *Sign-in options* → *Require sign-in* → Never

Comment: `I have no option for "require sign in after sleep" as there is no password set.`